# How can i get a value of parent div except children tag

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

```
<bdi>
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">$</span>
"75.47"
</bdi>
```

Now i want to access **bdi** value that is **74.47** only, how can i fetch it by using jquery. Here is my jquery Code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.qty').on('change',function(){
         // grab the price
         var price = $('bdi').children().not('span').html();
         var total_price = price * this.value;
         console.log(price, this.value, total_price);
    });
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - Would you mind adding on what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Where is the HTML relevant to that jQuery so that a proper answer can be provided :)

Comment: I am working on WooCommere project, and i have no idea that where is that html code is placed, Just give me idea, how can i fetch 75.47 value of bdi tag?

Comment: Bu using given jquery code, i am getting an Undefined value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `.text()` method to grab the `bdi` only and then use `.replace` to remove the dollar sign `$` as well the double quotes `""`.

Also, to remove the extra space we need to `.trim()` - In order to use maths we need convert the string to `integar` using `parseInt` methof to do the `multiplication` and then get the **total** `value` in the `console.log`

**Live Demo:** (Full working code)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.qty').on('change', function() {
    // grab the price
    var price = $('bdi').text().replace("$", "").replace(/\"/g, "").trim() //75.47
    var total_price = parseInt(price) * parseInt($(this).val());
    console.log(total_price); //some results after selecting the product
    console.log(price ); //75.47
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="qty">
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="25">Some Value 25</option>
  <option value="75">Some Value 75</option>
</select>

<bdi>
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">$</span>
  "75.47"
</bdi>
```

Using **parseFloat** Method to make sure the total in in `decimals` **100.9** for 2 qty

**Live Demo:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.qty').on('change', function() {
    // grab the price
    var price = $('bdi').text().replace("$", "").replace(/\"/g, "").trim() //75.47
    var total_price = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat($(this).val());
    console.log(total_price); //some results after selecting the product
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="qty">
  <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
  <option value="2">Qty 2</option>
  <option value="5">Qty 5</option>
</select>

<bdi>
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">$</span>
  "50.45"
</bdi>
```

Comment: Bro you have done a great job, But i am still not getting the thing that i want. See,
**75.47** is a dynamic value of a product, Now i want to get the total price after multiplying the product price by total quantity. For this, my mentioned code is almost correct, but the thing is, code is also fetching **$** sign. Due to this **$** sign i am getting an undefined value.
For example: I have a product which have a price $50.45 and i am purchasing 2 quantity of that product. The total price should be  **100.9**. Isn't it?

Comment: @UmarAnwar Happy to help Umar. I am removing the dollar sign after the text is fetched bro. Also you are multiplying `*` the value that you are NOT adding `+` two values - any text you have `bdi` you can just use my code to remove the `$` dollar sign and only get the numbers you have. Check my updated you can see in the console.log that 75.47 is showing as results.

Comment: @UmarAnwar Check my updated answer :) all working for your its showing `100.9` for qty 2 products in the `console.log`. In that we need to use `parseFloat` to get the decimals totals

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner. There are probably many other ways:

1. Clone the `bdi` element
2. Remove the `span` from the clone
3. Use `end()` to return to the cloned element
4. Get the inner text content
5. Remove the quotes

```js
const str = $('bdi').clone().find('span').remove().end().text().split('"')[1];
//                   ^ (1)                ^ (2).   ^ (3)  ^ (4) ^ (5)
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<bdi>
   <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">$</span>
"75.47"
</bdi>
```

Comment: It not working for me, its giving an undefined value.

Comment: When you click the "Run code snippet" button? Or in your own implementation?

Comment: In my own implementation,

Comment: Show me a [MRE]

Answer (score 1):

$(selector).text() will return value without html code in it.

Comment: this will **not** work as wanted by OP - please review your answer :)

Comment: Exactly, this is not what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var price = $('bdi').children().remove().end().text();
```

That will return **"75.47"**, you can remove quotes and convert to double

Comment: I tried your code, But i am not getting the answer that i want. Here is an output.
73.48146.9673.48146.96**22.98**15.981.9828.9834.98 2 NaN.
**22.98** is the actual price of the product, then why i am getting all these valuses?